# Record USB input and emulate it later

Tags: usb

Question:

Is there a software or device that can record USB data/signal coming into my computer from another device and also allow me to emulate and send that recorded data/signal to my computer later?

Details:

The computer is running on Windows 10. I would prefer the cheapest possible solution, but also want to know what the ideal method would be.

I tried to do some research into this, but I'm only finding software that I don't really understand like "USBPcap" and "Free USB Analyzer". Also, it sounds like they only capture and monitor USB traffic. Nothing suggests that any of these would be able to do the second part which is to emulate the recorded signal.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to replicate the USB device's input to my computer on a daily timer without requiring a person to be present every day at the same time.

I don't care about seeing the actual data packets or knowing any details of the USB protocol. I just want to record the USB input going into my computer and make the computer receive that identical input in the future.

Comment: What's the background of this... is it to, say, wake up the computer?

Comment: I have a system where I have to use a specific USB device in order to activate some programs/appliances. I want them to operate while I'm asleep or not at home. I can handle the daily automation aspect but I need to capture USB signal that would normally come from the device and emulate it.

Comment: Gotcha, software emulating a HASP key?

Comment: I just Googled what a HASP key is and that's not what I'm using. I'm using a USB fingerprint scanner but I don't want to wake up at 4am just to scan my fingerprint and also I need it to run when I'm on vacation. It also doesn't have to be a software solution (although that's probably best) if there exists some physical device that can do it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117474/how-to-sniff-a-usb-port-under-windows